# postMessage to change input content of iframe

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

I have an `iframe` with `different source origin`, is there a way to use `postMessage` to change value of an input inside this same `iframe` knowing that i have any control on it's source.?

I tried to inject a script that listen for the `postMessage` inside the `iframe`, but I am always blocked by `origin policy`.

Hope I am clear, please any help or clarification, I tried several tricks but witout any results.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no, the security is place to stop you hacking someone else page.

Their is a longer answer involving proxy servers, but then you are properly breaking a few of your countries laws around copyright and computer miss use.

Comment: Thank you @David. So there is no other solution without the intervention
of the server's owner?

Comment: Nope, you need to ask yourself why are you manipulating someone else page without their consent. If they want you to do this, then they would provide a way to do it.

Comment: No I am not trying to manipulate their page without their permission, they give me their API to work with it but I had problems to use it with javascript due to cross origin issues, I asked you because i want to be sure before I ask them to provide us a way to implementing it  via javascript to be able to use it in a smart TV, I'm working for a company and I am not trying to break any rules here